# Can't delete the last email

Tags: vba, outlook

If I select multiple emails, the sub deletes them all except the last one and then gives an error.

If I select one item it goes straight to the error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
For i = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1
' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863343.aspx
    Dim email As Outlook.MailItem
    Set email = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i)
    email.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

`Error -2147352567 (80020009)` Outlook item can't be deleted (translated from Dutch)

Comment: Are you going to make us look up that error number?  What is the message that goes with it?

Comment: the error says: outlook item can't be deleted (translated from dutch)

Comment: There's nothing else to the error?  No explanation as to why it can't be deleted?

Comment: No, there is nothing else in the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aldo had a valid point

turning the preview pane of makes it work

```
    Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
On Error Resume Next

' turn off preview plane to prevent error
Application.ActiveExplorer.ShowPane olPreview, False

For i = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1

    If i = 1 Then

    End If

   Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i).Delete

Next

Application.ActiveExplorer.ShowPane olPreview, True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Without having tested anything (you are not telling us what Outlook version you are using), I'd guess that you could try deleting the mail items without explicitly assigning them one by one:

```
For i = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1
    Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i).Delete
Next
```

This has the added benefit of being quicker to execute. In your code, attempting to delete the last remaining item from the selection makes the reference to the variable `email` void, which is probably something VBA doesn't like.

Comment: I did test it and it just gives a different error: Error 440 during exaction outlook can't delete the item (translated from Dutch)

Comment: You are making stuff up.  Can you provide some references to substantiate your claims?  "which is probably something VBA doesn't like" doesn't make a sound answer.  The fact is, your code and the OP's code is functionally equivalent.

Comment: Point taken. Thinking beyond the code posted above, is there a possibility that the mail item is opened somewhere, e.g. shown in a separate window? That might explain the issue. My suggestion indeed does not.

Comment: Aldo my have a point, i tried the script in a different viewing mode and turned the "reading" option off and that does the trick. Point is why can I move mail (to a different folder) when i'm "reading" it but can't delete it?

Comment: When you are displaying an item the application maintains a handle on it (a reference to the object) that prevents it from being deleted. Putting a mail item into another folder is not physically moving it (it's not like moving a file in Windows); it just alters some setting (i.e. the mail folder) of the item itself. The mail item keeps the same reference during this action, so it's allowed.